# running boost: lock free queues globally across multiple files

Tags: boost, pthreads, lock-free

I would like to run a variant of example 46.3 from this website
http://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.lockfree. I am on a linux system.

I would like to have the queue q be defined in a header file. I would like to have the produce and consume functions be in different files. So I would like to have global.h contain

```
    static boost::lockfree::queue<int> q{100};
    static std::atomic<int> sum{0};
    void *produce (void*);
    void *consume (void*);
```

I would then like to have a produce.cpp contain:

```
     void *produce( void*)
         {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; ++i)
q.push(i);

         }
```

and I would like to have a consume.cpp contain

```
         void *consume (void*)
         {
                int i;
         while (q.pop(i))
            sum += i;

                     }
```

I would then like to have my main.cpp contain

```
         #include iosteam
         #include iomanip
         #include global
         #include pthread

         int main () 
                  {pthread_t t1;
                  pthread_t t2;
                 pthread_t t3;


                           int t1_iret;
                   t1_iret = pthread_create( &t1, NULL, produce, NULL);
          if(t1_iret)
         {
                fprintf(stderr,"Error - pthread_create() return code:  %d\n",t1_iret);
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }

         int t2_iret;
       t2_iret = pthread_create( &t2, NULL, consume, NULL);
     if(t2_iret)
 {
     fprintf(stderr,"Error - pthread_create() return code: %d\n",t2_iret);
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }

          int t3_iret;
      t3_iret = pthread_create( &t3, NULL, consume, NULL);
      if(t3_iret)
  {
     fprintf(stderr,"Error - pthread_create() return code: %d\n",t3_iret);
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }



        pthread_join( t1, NULL);
        pthread_join( t2, NULL);
       pthread_join( t3, NULL);



                       return 0; }
```

Additionally, I was wondering if it would be possible to do what I have described with strings rather then integers.

edit1: when I try and make the queue be queue of strings I get::

/usr/local/include/boost/lockfree/queue.hpp: In instantiation of ‘class boost::l                                                                                                         ockfree::queue >’:
             /home/ubuntu/Project/src/main.cpp:15:37:   required from here
/usr/local/include/boost/lockfree/queue.hpp:87:5: error: static assertion failed                                                                                                 : (boost::has_trivial_destructor::value)
     BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT((boost::has_trivial_destructor::value));
     ^
/usr/local/include/boost/lockfree/queue.hpp:91:5: error: static assertion failed                                                                                                 : (boost::has_trivial_assign::value)
     BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT((boost::has_trivial_assign::value));
     ^
     In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/lockfree/queue.hpp:21:0,
                 from /home/ubuntu/Project/src/main.cpp:5:
/usr/local/include/boost/lockfree/detail/copy_payload.hpp: In instantiation of ‘                                                                                                 static void boost::lockfree::detail::copy_constructible_and_copyable::copy(T&, U                                                                                                 &) [with T = std::basic_string; U = int]’:
/usr/local/include/boost/lockfree/detail/copy_payload.hpp:49:25:   required from                                                                                                  ‘void boost::lockfree::detail::copy_payload(T&, U&) [with T = std::basic_string                                                                                                 ; U = int]’
/usr/local/include/boost/lockfree/queue.hpp:402:61:   required from ‘bool boost:                                                                                                 :lockfree::queue::pop(U&) [with U = int; T = std::basic_string; A0 = boost::parameter::void_; A1 = boost::parameter::void_; A2 = boost::par                                                                                                 ameter::void_]’
/home/ubuntu/Project/src/main.cpp:21:24:   required from here
/usr/local/include/boost/lockfree/detail/copy_payload.hpp:38:11: error: invalid                                                                                                  cast from type ‘std::basic_string’ to type ‘int’
         u = U(t);

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare, but not define, your variables in `global.h`:

```
extern boost::lockfree::queue<int> q;
extern std::atomic<int> sum;
```

Then you need to define them in a separate file, `global.cpp`:

```
boost::lockfree::queue<int> q{100};
std::atomic<int> sum{0};
```

I think this should fix your issue.  For details, see [How do I use extern to share variables between source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files-in-c)

---

As for the second part, asking why you can't make a lock-free queue of strings, well, that is answered by the error message: `has_trivial_destructor` is false for `std::string`, because it's a dynamically-sized string which allocates memory.  You won't be able to use it in this sort of lock-free queue.  You can try using a fixed-size string class instead, or `std::array<char, N>`.

Comment: Well, I tried it, and I am having two problems, 1) it seems that the global queue is not being updated across the header file. 2) additionally, I can't make a queue of strings.

Comment: @ArielBaron: OK, thanks for the details.  I updated my answer to fix (1).  As for (2), what do you mean you "can't"?  Did you get an error message?

Comment: For 2) I get an error and for 1)  the sum is displaying zero which indicates the queue is not being filled

Comment: @ArielBaron: "I get an error" is not useful.  What error exactly?  Paste the entire text.

Comment: I added the error to the question. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @ArielBaron: OK I answered the second part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125380/discussion-between-ariel-baron-and-john-zwinck).